# WordPress get user by email or meta key value with or relationship

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a field for email. when users submits form I want to filter the user by email or meta key "Partner_email". I need OR relations between fields and meta key.

```
$args = array (
        'email' => $_POST['email'],
        'relation' => 'OR',
        'meta_query' => array(
            // 'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'     => 'partner_email',
                'value'   => $_POST['email'],
                'compare' => '='
            )
        )
    );

// Create the WP_User_Query object
$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom query;

```
global $wpdb;

$email = $_POST['email'];
    
$users_query = "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->users AS users";
$users_query .= " LEFT JOIN $wpdb->usermeta AS usermeta ON (users.ID = usermeta.user_id)";
$users_query .= " WHERE users.user_email='$email'";
$users_query .= " OR (usermeta.meta_key='partner_email' AND usermeta.meta_value='$email')";
$users_query .= " group by users.ID";
$users_ids = $wpdb->get_col($users_query);
```